# don't allow user to access profile.php but allow him to access profile.php?username=

Tags: php

i know the question is a bit weird but i don't  want user to access profile.php without there being the ?username. because it displays notice that username isn't defined. is there anyway i can do that? for example user clicks on username he gets redirected to profile.php?username=y but i don't want him to type in the url profile.php. if he does that i want to redirect him to another page is that possible. i tired getting the url and if it's profile.php only i want to redirect him but if it has ?username in it i want to show the profile page

Comment: "i tired getting the url and if it's profile.php only i want to redirect him ..." It's be helpful to see this attempt. What you're trying to achieve shouldn't be difficult, but it'd be more helpful to you to have someone explain *why* what you tried didn't work and how to fix to it in a way that *will* work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could check if the `?username=` exists by doing:

```
if(isset($_GET['username'])){
    // The user tried to access profile.php?username=
}else{
    // The user went to profile.php
}
```

For more information about `$_GET`:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: That's because you already printed stuff before you call `header`.

Comment: i have fixed it by adding ob_start(); at the top is that bad practice?

Comment: It's not bad @theprogrammer. You just have to understand what it does. Here's the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

you could always handle this through the .htaccess file or use a redirect function like the one below of the field that you are looking for is not provided in the $_REQUEST:

```
function RedirectToURL($url) {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
}
```

However, if I understand you properly, in my opinion this would be poor programming.  Perhaps you could use a Request Helper object instead in your profile.php page (if you dont have a front controller).  From there, you will be able to manipulate the request details and react accordignly.  Here is a sugestion:

```
    class RequestHelper {
    private static $instance;
    private static $properties;

    public static function instance() {
        if (is_null(self::$instance)) {self::$instance = new self();}
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct() {
        $this->init();
    }

    protected function init() {
        // updating properties with fields from submitted form.
        if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
            self::$properties = $_REQUEST;
        }
    }

    private function getProperty($key) {
        if (isset(self::$properties[$key])) {
            return self::$properties[$key];
        }

        return null;
    }

    private function setProperty($key, $val) {
        self::$properties[$key] = $val;
    }

    public function getUserName() {
        return getProperty("username");
    }
}


echo RequestHelper::instance()->getUserName();
```

cheers